# Unusual String Error

Tags: c#, string

I am working with some sample code generously given to me by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948691/genetic-programming-implementation/949453#949453), and when i enter a long string to match it crashes at some point with an IndexOutOfRangeException. What's strange is that when i inspect the string, it appears to be set to the words "System.Char[]". Why does this happen, and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
    var mutated = member.Str.ToCharArray();
    Convert.ToChar((member.Str[ipos] + delta)%123).ToString().CopyTo(0, mutated, ipos, 1);
    member.Str = mutated.ToString();
```

Should be, as Jon suggests:

```
    var mutated = member.Str.ToCharArray();
    Convert.ToChar((member.Str[ipos] + delta)%123).ToString().CopyTo(0, mutated, ipos, 1);
    member.Str = new string(mutated);
```

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect that somewhere you've got:

```
char[] chars = ...;
string myString = chars.ToString();
```

instead of

```
char[] chars = ...;
string myString = new string(chars);
```